# Gradient In Android

Tags: android

I want to add gradient to my page. I have used java code throughout and absolutely no xml cose has been used. I tried looking for some codes online, but since am new to this field, couldn't get it right. Can you please help me with how to insert gradient effect in my page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the [GradientDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a LinearGradient or a RadialGradient and set this as your Paint's shader.

See the doc for http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RadialGradient.html here, and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient.html here.